# Android:I want to provide progress animation (horizontal) to display progress of download in android instead of using progress bar. How can i do that?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to provide progress animation (horizontal) to display progress of download in android. How can i do that?

Comment: What is a "progress animation (horizontal)"?

Comment: Progress Animations are the animations that are used to show the progress. There are majorly two kinds of animations generally used in showing progress - circular and horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [**Progress Bar**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

Comment: It is not the default progress bar provided by android. Of-course it will show progress but I want to give some animations.